# Multiple Language-Files for same language in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I am using Angular 5. i18n translation files are all stored in a single folder by default.

[image]

The problem is, that i need to use a "basic" translation file that is provided from another project and in addition to that i want to add a second translation file for all the additional translations that come up during development. Something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to have multiple language files that can be used for the same language?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: I didnt.. Maybe the only Solution is to merge them with a custom script

Comment: Did you find a solution because I’m trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular i18n Merge Files](https://github.com/marcioggs/ng-i18n-merge-files#readme).

Run:

```
npx ng-i18n-merge-files -f xlf
```

And it will generate the following files with the merged content in the same folder:

```
messages.de.xlf
messages.en.xlf
messages.fr.xlf
messages.nl.xlf
messages.pt.xlf
messages.ru.xlf
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular translations are loaded by a TranslateLoader which has an abstract getTranslation method. It is common to use a TranslateHttpLoader to read translations from assets.

This is an example:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json?cacheBuster=' + new Date().getTime());
}
```

To use translations from multiple files, you can forkJoin requests and map the responses into a single translation file.
I also provided an example on how to change the path of directories, even though for me the path is same.

```
export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private config: { uiPath: string; libPath: string }) {
  }

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const uiUrl = `${this.config.uiPath}/${lang}.json`;
    const libraryUrl = `${this.config.libPath}/${lang}-map.json`;
    const suffix = '?cacheBuster=' + new Date().getTime();

    return forkJoin({
      uiTranslations: this.http.get(`${uiUrl}${suffix}`),
      libTranslations: this.http.get(`${libraryUrl}${suffix}`),
    }).pipe(
      map(response => ({...response.libTranslations, ...response.uiTranslations}))
    );
  }
}

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new CustomTranslateLoader(http, {
    uiPath: './assets/i18n',
    libPath: './assets/i18n',
  });
}
```